# Uploading files through streaming with SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I want to upload files from my Javascript client to my WebAPI. 
With this I want to have a progress bar. My Idea was to cut the files up in chunks and then stream them via SingalR since we are using SingalR anyway.

This is my code:

API:

```
public async Task UploadStream(IAsyncEnumerable<string> stream)
{
    string buffer = "";

    await foreach (var item in stream)
    {
        buffer += item;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(buffer);
}
```

Javascript:

```
let base64 = data;
let chunks = base64.match(/.{1,25000}/g);

const subject = new signalR.Subject();
hub.getConnection().send("UploadStream", subject);

chunks.forEach((chunk: string) => {
    subject.next(chunk);
});

subject.complete();
```

Now, this works, and it takes about 0.3 seconds to upload a 2.8MB image on localhost. But, my question is: Is this a good or bad practice? Or is it better to upload files as a multipart request?

Comment: Please don't reinvent multipart file upload.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this would be bad? I am still learning, so I would highly appreciate it!

Comment: SignalR is a wrapper over sockets. It falls back to WebSocket, long pooling and etc based on browser compatibility. It meant to be used for messages, not large files. Multipart file upload was designed for large files. Sending files over SignalR is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thanks.